# Updating component with rendered attribute are not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a email Input and i want to validade it and show a icon with it is correct or not. I use a p:ajax with a blur event. But the attribute with a rendered attribute are not working.
I use primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.2.
Here are picture before https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yi2246wzqgymcr/before.JPG  and after https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bii3bv145s99ge/after.JPG

```
                <p:row>
                    <p:column style="width:400px">
                        <h:outputLabel for="inpTextRegEmail" styleClass="outputRight" value="#{msg['regi_mail']}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:30px">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="requiredIcon" value="∗" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:350px">
                        <p:inputText style="width:350px" id="inpTextRegEmail" value="#{regiBean.user.EMAIL}"
                            required="true" maxlength="75">
                            <f:validator immediate="true" validatorId="at.dccs.csm.gui.jsf.validator.emailValidator" />
                            <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"
                                update="correctMail   correctMailIcon incorrectMailIcon  emailMSG hiasl" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:410px">
                        <h:panelGroup id="mailTip" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x" />
                        <p:tooltip for="mailTip" value="Some Help" />
                        <p:message id="emailMSG" for="inpTextRegEmail" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>

                    <p:column style="width:400px">
                        <p:outputLabel styleClass="outputRight" value="Username" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:30px">
                        <p:outputLabel styleClass="requiredIcon" value=" " />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel id="correctMail" style="color: green;" value="#{regiBean.user.EMAIL}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <h:panelGroup id="correctMailIcon" class="fa fa-check-circle  fa-2x"
                            rendered="#{regiBean.correctUsername == true}" />
                        <h:panelGroup id="incorrectMailIcon" class="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x"
                            rendered="#{regiBean.correctUsername == false}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
```

Answer (score 0):

`blur` event is not an event. It must be related to `<p:inputText />` component events.

Use `onblur` event in `<p:ajax />` component for event firing. The events supported by `<p:inputText />` are `onblur, onchange, onclick, ondblclick, onfocus, onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup, onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseout, onmouseover, onmouseup, onselect`. Use any one of these attributes in event attribute of `<p:ajax />` component.

Update componet with below code

```
<p:ajax event="onblur" process="@this"
     update="correctMail   correctMailIcon incorrectMailIcon  emailMSG hiasl" />
```

Place the cursor in-between the primefaces components and click `Ctrl + Space` the list of attributes is displayed and events name starts with **On** like `onblur... etc`.

Comment: the event onblur is not supported in the p:ajax tag

Comment: place this inpTextRegEmail id `p:ajax` update attribute.

Comment: do you mean this ?
 <p:ajax id="myid" immediate="true" event="blur" process="@this"  update="inpTextRegEmail correctMail   correctMailIcon incorrectMailIcon  emailMSG hiasl"
          />

Comment: @bvb1909 again why are you using `event="blur"` it is wrong. `<p:ajax id="myid" immediate="true" event="onblur" process="@this" update="inpTextRegEmail correctMail correctMailIcon incorrectMailIcon emailMSG hiasl" />`. Read my answer again. Supports which events in `<p:inputText/>` component.

Comment: I am using blur because if i use onblur I get an message that the event is not supported